# Event listener does not seem to recognise my class?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

I have a mobile menu that opens when the open menu button is clicked. I am trying to add a trap focus functionality to the menu when it is open so that users cannot access outside of my menu with a keyboard when tabbing.

I have used an event listener to listen for tab and shift tab keydown events in the menu. The logic is that if the active element does not have a class that only my menu items have then to lock focus back onto the close button of my menu.

Problem is that the focus gets stuck on my close button instantly and I cannot move it (even though it has the class "in-listview"). I realise that my code may not be the best way to implement this feature but for now I would just like to know why my class does not seem to be recognised and I can tidy up after. My app is built using ReactJS.

```
openNav = () => {
const listView = document.querySelector(".listview");

listView.classList.remove('closeMobMenu');
listView.style.visibility = "visible";
listView.classList.add('openMobMenu');
document.addEventListener('keydown', this.trapTabMobMenu)//Maybe move this to componentDidMount()?
}

trapTabMobMenu = (event) => {

if(event.keyCode === 9) { // if the tab key is pressed in the mobile menu
  const closeBtn = this.closeBtn;
  let activeElement = document.activeElement;

  if(event.shiftKey) { // shift-tab
    event.preventDefault();
    //if focused element does not have class in-list-view
    if(!activeElement.classList.contains("in-listview")) {
      closeBtn.focus();
    }
  } else { // normal tab
    event.preventDefault();
    if(!activeElement.classList.contains("in-listview")) {
      closeBtn.focus();
    }
  }
}
if(event.keyCode === 27) {
  this.closeNav();
}
```

}

```
<button ref={(close) => { this.closeBtn = close; }} className="closebtn in-listview" onClick={closeNav} onKeyPress={handleKeyPress} tabIndex="2">&times;</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.activeElement` is not set until after the focus event has been completed, so the above code is not performing your logic on the new element that is firing the `onFocus` event.

You need to change `document.activeElement` to be `event.target` then perform your logic.

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/activeElement